# Как выполнить код при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: android

Делаю приложения с обоями для телефона, но не получается сделать кнопку "Установить обои" под картинкой.

**full_image.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Сделал метод `setawall()`:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
    } 

    public void setaswall(View view) {
      WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
      try {
        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

а как прикрутить его к кнопке понятия не имею

Comment: вообще не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: Поправил текст !

Comment: Как обработать [нажатие на кнопку](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php)

Comment: ну гуглом я пользоваться умею вроде

Comment: ну а в чем проблема, что уже сделали и почему не получается

Comment: все на том же этапе, сижу, читаю, учу

Comment: проблему решил ))) забыл прописать setawall в full_image.xml:


Спасибо за помощь